# Why does the following R command crash the moment I try and access the new object

Tags: r

Why does the following code execute:

```
dx4[,6:ncol(dx4)] = gsub("R7", NA ,dx4[,6:ncol(dx4)])
```

But then crash when I try to access dx4?

Comment: I found code that works, I don't understand why this code doesn't.
And yes it is a dataframe.

Comment: No clue didn't try it. :P This is more of a why question than a how question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dx4[, 6:ncol(dx4)] <- do.call("cbind", lapply(dx4[, 6:ncol(dx4)],
                                              function(x) gsub("R7", NA ,x)))
```

Make sure the data.frame dx4 is not empty otherwise ncol behaves not as you might expect.
Hope this helps

Comment: I found an answer already, thank you. Im just trying to understand why this fails? I think this is a compiler issue because otherwise I'd get an error, and accessing the new object wouldn't crash my computer.